# C# - Get path of file in project - after build

Tags: c#

I write a code that  upload file and i need the path of file.
i write something like that:

```
private string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.
    BaseDirectory, @"folder1\Files\", "file.jpg");
```

return me this path:

```
C:\Users\name\source\repos\projectFile\bin\Debug\folder1\Files
```

Is it possible to write this line in another way maybe shorter:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain. BaseDirectory, @"folder1\Files\", "file.jpg");
```

the main purpose of this is that i want to run this code from server 
and the path can be change according to each server.
Note: I marked in visual studio in the settings of the file that I want to upload copy of this file to the debug folder.

thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for. Are you saying that line of code is too long?

Comment: There's not point in having two hard-coded strings next to each other. those can be combined into a single argument

Comment: In a server environment, you don't save files to your application folders (which will be read-only by default). Please read this: https://dotnettips.wordpress.com/2017/02/20/net-framework-core-getting-the-app-data-folder/